# Dynamically generated checkbox gets removed when checkbox check is changed

Tags: asp.net

I am dynamically generating checkbox on the basis of text entered in a textbox. When any of the checkbox is checked\unchecked, the checkbox gets removed. When I inspect element I cannot find checkbox and its change event is not fired. All these controls are in update panel.
Code is as follows:

```
   <ajax:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtProducts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onblur="return validate();" OnTextChanged="txtProducts_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
     </td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <panel runat="server" id="panelDynamicCheckbox"></panel>
     </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
  </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
        <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtProducts" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
   </ajax:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void txtProducts_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] products = txtProducts.Text.Split(',');
        CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[products.Length];
        int countForCheckbox = 0;
        foreach (string product in products)
        {
            chk[countForCheckbox] = new CheckBox();
            chk[countForCheckbox].ID = product;
            chk[countForCheckbox].Text = product;
            chk[countForCheckbox].Checked = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].AutoPostBack = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].EnableViewState = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Dynamic_CheckChanged);
            panelDynamicCheckbox.Controls.Add(chk[countForCheckbox]);
                countForCheckbox++;
        }
    }

    protected void Dynamic_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        lblProductDetails.Text = "Done";
    }
```

On textchange it shows the checkboxes but when I uncheck checkbox is gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer.
On postback dynamically created elements get removed so on postback I have to generate elements again. So in page_load I did following:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
      if (IsPostBack)
      {
        CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[products.Length];
        int countForCheckbox = 0;
        panelDynamicCheckbox.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (string product in products)
        {
            chk[countForCheckbox] = new CheckBox();
            chk[countForCheckbox].ID = product;
            chk[countForCheckbox].Text = product;
            chk[countForCheckbox].Checked = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].AutoPostBack = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].EnableViewState = true;
            chk[countForCheckbox].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Dynamic_CheckChanged);
            panelDynamicCheckbox.Controls.Add(chk[countForCheckbox]);
            countForCheckbox++;
        }
      }
   }
```